# VBA how to automate CTRL + F search

Tags: excel, vba

How to automate CTRL + F search with specific value put ..

example: i have two sheets with name lists , i want copy a name (value ) 
in specific cell from sheet 1 then put it in search to sheet 2 to find it .

Comment: Use the macro recorder. Start recording, do exactly what you want to do, and stop recording when you're done. Use the macro editor to look at the code Excel generates for the macro.

Comment: You can use a Range member, "Find." -- `set rng = ws.UsedRange.Find(TextBox1)`.You can check out the Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neerozz, perhaps using WorkSheet_Change events, on both sheets - one applying an interior color, and the other telling the source sheet to adjust the Find sheet to change the color back to no fill (`ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0`). You didn't specify you needed to add colors to your sheet, but will make it visually easy, interactive, and easy on resources.

This code should be used for sheet you're checking for:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wsCheck As Worksheet
Dim intFound As Integer

Set wsCheck = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
intFound = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
(wsCheck.UsedRange.Cells, UsedRange.Cells)

If intFound > 0 Then: ActiveCell.Interior.Color = rgbCoral

End Sub
```

Danny,
[ExcelVBADude](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA?view_as=subscriber)